# $this->action to Display a certain action from a controller - ZEND

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

I'm trying to build a menu for my website that I'm building with ZEND. I'm a newbie to ZEND.
So, I created an action catmenuAction() in the controller called BlogCateogoriesController. I created a veiw script for it too.

now in the master.phtml file, I'm trying to call this view script to render my menu. Actually i think this is how I'll bring latest news, comments, Tweets to my pages (the way lika MODULES in Joomla do).

In my master.phtml file I declared

```
<?php $this->layout()->categoriesList = $this->action('catmenu', 'Blog_BlogCategories'); ?>
```

and now I'm getting this terrible error saying that it can't find Blog_BlogCategoriesController:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (Blog_BlogCategories)' in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:248 Stack trace: #0 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\View\Helper\Action.php(135): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 [internal function]: Zend_View_Helper_Action->action('catmenu', 'Blog_BlogCatego...') #2 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(350): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 [internal function]: Zend_View_Abstract->__call('action', Array) #4 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\application\layouts\master.phtml(20): Zend_View->action('catmenu', 'Blog_BlogCatego...') #5 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\View.php(108): include('D:\Server\xampp...') #6 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(888): Zend_View->_run('D:\Server\xampp...') #7 D:\Ser in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336
```

HELP ME OUT PLEASE!!!

Comment: Check the controller names. See if they are identical. See if you got something written on routing file. I am not a Zend user so i can only suggest u things. I am not sure if my suggestion works!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax for Zend_View_Helper_Action is this:

`action( string $action, string $controller, string $module = null, array $params = array() ) : string`

So where you call:

`$this->action('catmenu', 'Blog_BlogCategories');`

I assume you have a class Blog_BlogCategoriesController in the 'Blog' module. You would need to call:

`$this->action('catmenu', 'BlogCategories', 'Blog');`

Comment: thanks a lot!!! I was looking for definition of action function, what parameters it takes, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to make a script below according to my understanding. you have used master.phtml file which you have to mentioned where is is located and how is it related to the problem. Use these http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html
command line to create project then module and then Controller and also layout.

The rest is explained below (and hope this helps)

```
applicaiton
  -config
  -controller
    -IndexController.php
  -forms
  -layouts
    -scripts
      -layout.phtml
  -models
  -modules
    -Blog
      -contollers
        -IndexController.php
        -CateogoriesController.php
      -models
      -views
        -helpers
    -scripts
      -error
      -index
        -index.phtml
          -cateogories
            -index.php
  -views
    -helpers
    -scripts
      -error
      -index
        -index.phtml
      -partials
        -menu.phtml
  -Bootstrap.php
```

**layout/scripts/layout.phtml**

```
<?php
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
$this->headTitle($this->headtitle);
echo $this->doctype(); 
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
<body>
<!-- loading menu -->
<?php echo $this->partial('partials/menu.phtml', 'default'); ?>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the layout script, note that layout()->content will load your current view file
so you dont need to chanage any thing here
here the i have called partial view which is link to the view which is of default module

**modules/Blog/controllers/CateogoriesController.php**

```
<?php
class Blog_CateogoriesController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {

    }
    //Default function
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }
}
```

This is the basic structure of your Blog_CateogoriesController class

**modules/Blog/views/scripts/cateogories/index.phtml**

```
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="contant"></div>
```

your basic page layout

**views/scripts/partials/menu.phtml**

```
<!-- menu -->
<ul> <li> </li> <ul>
```

your menu html code